# AutoLayout: layout consistency with proportional element spacing with 3.5" and 4" screens

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to use AutoLayout to position controls with proportional vertical spacing between them (avoid cropping on a 3.5" screen, avoid blank bottom space on a 4" screen).

As suggested in other answers, I can use spacer views with "Equal Height" constraints, changing multiplier where necessary. However, the final layout is not pixel-perfect, so the engine can't position them consistently.

The symptoms:

1. When I do an "Update All Frames" in IB, it doesn't fix misplaced views, but merely replaces them with other set of misplaced views.
2. More importantly, at run time, I can see the controls momentarily jump a few pixels up or down, whenever I enter the view.

How to I achieve the same consistent layout every time?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Height constraints for the the controls which you want to place on the screen vertically
2. Create outlets for the height constraints.
3. For 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen, change the value of height constraints' constant.
4. If changing the height doesn't solve the purpose, create Vertical Space Constraints and set their values accordingly.