# Button position issues in different screens in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have set a subview in a view controller, in which there is a button i have set constraints of that subview and preview it on different screens it looks fine in preview but when i run on different screen it changes the position . The subview is on the bottom left of the view controller. The constraints i have used are,
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep it at the bottom left of the view controller then you need only four constraints: leading, bottom, height, width. It will stick there only.

Comment: have u  seen the screen shots? @Amit

Comment: hey Oneeb, you need to set a relative height constraint and aspect ratio as 1:1 instead of a fixed height, width constraints. Otherwise, in smaller screens the button will overlap

Comment: i have used all these constraints but when i test it on real device it comes above the button i don't know why. @Amit

Comment: The constraints that you have added will design the UI look good on 6 and 6s, but for 5s you have to make the UI scrollable.

Comment: How to set the all that as u described above? @JenJose

Comment: can't we give one time constraints so that it can adjust on all screens? @Amit

Comment: @JenJose is right. For you query , don't set fixed height to buttons and views,  use aspect ratio.

Comment: how to set relative height than? @Amit

Comment: @Oneeb , you need to read more on relative size constraints. Thats easy, the key is instead of constant, we use multiplier. Now for your design, you need to set a relative constraint for top Image, then in a fixed height view you will place the three buttons and layout it on the screen and for the bottom-left button you will use a relative height-width. Simple!

Comment: have u have any link that can simply explain the concept of relative size. @JenJose

Comment: Check this for relative proportional size constraints https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started  and for relative positioning check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882717/ios-proportional-spacing-with-autolayout (which is based on center constraints and same can be done with BottomLayout constraint) . start with these, you will gradually pick up other tricks..

Comment: Thanks i will follow this. @JenJose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approach for this programmatically and using storyboard.

I have implemented this in my project using storyboard with the help of these links:

- [Xcode AutoLayout, Make Margin proportional with height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074431/xcode-autolayout-make-margin-proportional-with-height)
- [autolayout - make height of view relative to half superview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935825/autolayout-make-height-of-view-relative-to-half-superview-height)

Please check if it helps in your scenario.